# Wand: drop shadow on image

Tags: python-3.x, imagemagick, wand

I am looking for the equivalent function in wand - python of the following imagemagick code:

```
convert image.png \( +clone -background black -shadow 60x4+0+4 \) +swap -background none -layers merge +repage image_with_shadow.png
```

This is what I'm using but the end result is slightly different from the above code: I'm not able to set the colour of the shadow nor to center the shadow as in imagemagick.

```
from wand.image import Image

img = Image(filename = "image.png")
with img.clone() as shadow:
  shadow.shadow(60, 4, 0, 4)
  shadow.save(filename = "shadow.png")

with Image(filename = "shadow.png") as back:
  with Image(filename = "image.png") as front:
     with back.clone() as new_image:
       new_image.composite(front,4,4)
       new_image.save(filename = "image_with_shadow.png")
```

Comment: Use "merge_layers" with option "merge". See https://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.6.7/wand/image.html and https://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.6.7/wand/image.html#wand.image.IMAGE_LAYER_METHOD rather than composite.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, might be not the 100% precise answer to your question, but still helpful. I created a simple **drop_shadow** function which applies on non transparent pixels. Uses Pillow and numpy

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image, ImageFilter

def add_shadow(img, shadow_tone=200, blur_radius=8):
    blurred_img = np.array(img)
    blurred_img[:,:,:3] = shadow_tone

    blurred_img = Image.fromarray(np.array(blurred_img))
    blurred_img = blurred_img.filter(ImageFilter.GaussianBlur(radius=blur_radius))

    background = Image.new("RGB", img.size, (255, 255, 255))
    background.paste(blurred_img, mask=blurred_img.split()[3])
    background.paste(img, mask=img.split()[3])
    
    return background

img = Image.open('something_with_transparency.png')
img = add_shadow(img)
```

Comment: This gives me an error
`background.paste(blurred_img, mask=blurred_img.split()[3])
IndexError: tuple index out of range
`

Comment: @HenriqueBucher The "3" in the blurred_img.split()[3] takes the 4th channel (alpha) of your image. Probably your image has only 3 channels with no alpha transparency